# Shimming a package with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

There's a javascript file that I need to use in my project as a dependency. It doesn't have a github repository, it's not on bower, or npm, it just lives here.

http://a.klaviyo.com/media/js/learnmarklet.js

I can install it with bower with:

```
bower install http://a.klaviyo.com/media/js/learnmarklet.js --save
```

I know that it will then live in my project at:

```
./bower_components/learnmarklet/index.js
```

And I know it attaches a variable called `_learnq` to the global window object.

What I want is simply this.

```
var _learnq = require("klaviyo")
```

I need to alias `klaviyo` something like this.

```
{
  "klaviyo": "./bower_components/learnmarklet/index.js"
}
```

And "shim" an export of the `_learnq` variable like this.

```
{
  "klaviyo": "_learnq"
}
```

How can I do this with webpack?

This is what i've tried, this is what my `webpack.config.js` looks like.

```
module.exports = {
  resolve:{
    alias:{
      "klaviyo": "./bower_components/learnmarklet/index.js"
    }
  },
  externals: {
    klaviyo: "_learnq"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your example, your code will kind of conflict, the `externals` basically says

```
require('klaviyo')
```

should be rewritten to

```
window._learnq
```

and the alias says

```
require('klaviyo')
```

basically does

```
require('./bower_components/learnmarklet/index.js')
```

What I would recommend is this:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve:{
    alias:{
      // Make it so that 'require' finds the right file.
      "klaviyo": "./bower_components/learnmarklet/index.js"
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      // Rewrite the file so that it exports the window global.
      test: __dirname + '/bower_components/learnmarklet/index.js',
      loader: 'exports?window._learnq'
    }]
  }
}
```

You's need to `npm install exports-loader` as well.

Comment: I'm happy to accept this as the answer. I believe it should work. I'm getting some weird errors on my side because of the way this script was created. It's apparently looking for nodejs packages fs, file, and system https://gist.github.com/reggi/628736bdb70a2a98deae

Comment: Ahh that will definitely depend on the usage. If the code depends on the filesystem for something critical, the library may simply be unusable in the browser.

Comment: No! It's for the browser! It just has conditional requirements for when it's run within node. When run within webpack those conditionals break because it's a CommonJS environment.

Comment: You can deactivate the CommonJS part with the imports-loader. Check out http://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html for further help.